# Upgraded to Android 10 - can't change MAC address

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, custom-roms, mac-address

Today I upgraded to Android 10, more precisely to unofficial build of Lineage OS. My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro (whyred). I am used to changing my MAC address, because our school tracks network usage. I got around it by setting my MAC to MAC of one of schools iPads. After the upgrade I can't change my MAC anymore! I turn the WiFi off as always (otherwise I would get some error like resource busy) and set the MAC using following command:

```
ip link set wlan0 address MACHERE
```

Or

```
busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether MACHERE
```

In both cases the MAC gets changed, but after turning the WiFi on again and connecting to  WiFi, it gets resettled back to where it was.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas what can be causing this? I have tried (so far):

- multiple different kernels
- rebooting

Fixed by editing `wlan_mac.bin`:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add the solution to an answer with some explanation for others benefit?

Comment: Android 10 has by default MAC randomization activated: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization

Comment: @Robert that's why it'd be interesting to know how OP got a fixed MAC address by modifying a WiFi firmware file.

Comment: @Robert The WiFi driver needs special implementation for random MACs. I was also checking that. My build has it disabled. I have permanently changed the MAC by modifying /persist/wlan_mac.bin as shown above in edit. I think that the fact I can not change my mac as I used to do before is because this ROM uses Xiaomi official WiFi driver. The fix sadly probably only works for devices with same driver/modem configuration.